# PHP count mysql row with changed date format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have next problem:
My table date format was: LIKE **2017-01-08 18:50:25** (with time).

When i use sql query like

```
'SELECT date FROM table WHERE date = "2017-01-08"'
```

My row was empty, i need COUNT all row with same (today) date WITHOUT TIME.

*Note, i will not change INSERT date time!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to get the date portion of the datetime field and compare it to today. Use [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) to get the number of records that match your query.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()
```

You can also replace [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) with [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now), [`CURRENT_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date), and [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it in the following way

```
'SELECT date FROM table WHERE date_format(date,'%Y-%m-%d') = "2017-01-08"'
```

the date_format is mysql function which return date according to your pattern the above pattern only return the Y-m-d from the datetime
I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

plz change your statement equal operator to greater than

'SELECT date FROM table WHERE date > "2017-01-08"'

as by default if time portion is not present then it is putting 00:00...